# add bitmap too arraylist

Tags: arraylist, bitmap, android-volley

i have used **volley.jar** lib and download a image. I want to add this bitmap to a **arraylist** . but it doesn't work and the size off arraylist is always = 0

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RequestQueue queue;
ImageView img;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps ;
public static final String URL_BASE = "http://192.166.1.2:8080/book/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(URL_BASE + "photos/flower",
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                   bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                }
            }, 220, 220, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, new 
 Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage(), 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);

    img.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(0));

    }
}
```

Comment: please check your response . are you getting bitmaps in your response?

Comment: yes. i tested :
public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
and it worked

Comment: have you checked its going to OnResponse not OnError

Comment: yess.. i recived photo. and used it for setImageBitmap in onResponse method. but i want to save it in array list, iwant to add sevral bitmap in one arraylist.